# Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 - Rails on Docker compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm trying to run elastic search on docker. I build a container for rails app connected with my db container. I want to connect this rails container with the elastic container but I get this error

Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200)

when I run docker-compose up these urls work fine 0.0.0.0:3000, 0.0.0.0:9200

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    command:  bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_HOST: db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    entrypoint: docker/entrypoint.sh
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.14.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200"
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - "ELASTIC_HOST=elasticsearch"
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    networks:
      - elastic
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

When I run docker-compose up and access 0.0.0.0:9200 through the browser. I get this response

```
{
  "name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_name" : "es-docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "eYnzMPJAQsGJ_QGco2mF-A",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.14.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "dd5a0a2acaa2045ff9624f3729fc8a6f40835aa1",
    "build_date" : "2021-07-29T20:49:32.864135063Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: `"ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200"` this should be setted for the `web` container, not for the `elasticsearch` container

Comment: any update in this?

Answer (score 1):

Your 'web' service in the docker-compose file does not have anything running on its localhost port 9000.

However, it is part of a network (created by docker-compose) with a number of other services (elasticsearch and db).
The elasticsearch service is reacheable in that network on host 'elasticsearch' port 9200. Better said: http://elasticsearch:9200/